# VMware SVGA II Adapter in Kali Linux 2020.2

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, nvidia, graphic-card

During grub boot, I have to add `nomodeset` parameter, else Kali Linux 2020.2 won't be able to boot inside VirtualBox.

Then, I was trying to install nvidia drivers on VM when found this article.

> Do not attempt this in a VM. It is possible in theory, however this
>   likely will not work and we do not recommend that users attempt this.

https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/

I notice that vga detected in guest OS (Kali) is `VMware SVGA II Adapter` while the host OS is using NVIDIA

Guest OS

```
kali@kali:~$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
kali@kali:~$
```

Host OS

```
wolf@linux:~$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
wolf@linux:~$
```

If the driver not installed, I have to add `nomodeset` parameter every time during boot process.

How do I fix this problem permanently?

Comment: why is your question tagged `virtualbox`, `nvidia` and `graphic-card` when it is not about any of those things ... your question is about grub configuration and 95% of your post is not even related to the actual question

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue with a Kali VM in ESXi.

In order to edit the GRUB config so that you don't have to manually enter the nomodeset option on each boot, you can:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

and then add nomodeset to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

And then save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X, then simply run:

`sudo update-grub`

However I've found that doing so leaves me with particularly small resolution options for the VM.  I attempted to edit the resolution options using xrandr, but still have not had success.  If anyone knows how to resolve that, I'd be happy to hear about it.